# How to design large library?

Tags: architecture

I have the problem of housing a large library.

Typical residential architecture uses built-in bookcases that line the walls and leave an open floor for the library with tables and couches. For me the problem with this is that the book-to-square-foot ratio is too low. I have about 10,000 books so I need a more space efficient design.

On the other end of the spectrum, institutional libraries use rows of two-side bookshelves that fill up the room. I find that this arrangement makes the room feel crowded and unfriendly, almost cave like, a dark forest of books.

Is there some kind of happy medium between these two extremes?

Comment: How much space do you have? Line all of the walls with bookshelves, and fill half the room with 2-sided bookshelves. This leaves half of the room open for a table and chair, couch, or whatever.

Comment: Maybe line the walls with rows of 2-sided bookshelves such that each row has one end attached to the wall with the other end pointing into the room - then play with the ratio of space between rows vs the length of each row. 1:1 would double the storage compared to a simple flat line-the-walls approach.

Comment: There's a wide range - go visit a few libraries with measuring tape in hnd if you don't manage guesstimating well. "Stacks" are prone to being cave-like, but institutional libraries have many other spaces with many other layouts. Using "middle shelves" that are not full height (so you can see over them) can make it feel more open, for instance. So can taller walls/ceiling, with either the "rolling library ladder" arrangement or a full-on balcony for access. OTOH, you could have an area of modern rolling shelves (many shelves, only one aisle space, the shelves move so the aisle space can move.)

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches come to mind.

- Vertical space.  Use floor to ceiling shelving.  Depending on ceiling height, you either keep some form of step stool handy, or a ladder (sometimes attached to a track to keep it vertical and minimize encroachment on room space, and you roll it to where you need it).
- Another approach is to use "layers" of shelving units.  There will be a row of built-in bookcases lining the wall.  Immediately in front of that is another row that is individual units on wheels or rollers, usually with a track or guides, and a gap.  You roll the front units aside to access the back units.  You nearly double the storage capacity with a minimal loss of additional room space.

Actually, there's a third approach I discovered for myself.  I had nowhere near 10,000 books, but a lot, and moved them from house to house, and ate up space in each house.  I finally realized (or more accurately, my wife "gently suggested"), that:

1. I hadn't looked at the vast majority in years and most of them, I probably never would again.
2. If I ever needed to refer to one, it would be unusual for the information not be be available online.  And finding things online is usually faster than finding it in a library of hardcopy.
3. It costs money and wastes space to store/display books, lug them from place to place, etc.
4. The paper dust from books, and the house dust that collects on them, is an allergen.

So I went through them and realized that she was right.  You can get a double benefit by not only not having most of them, but by selling them for cash (easy online), or donating them and getting a tax deduction.  So I'll just throw the option out there.

Comment: For that matter,  torrent ebook versions of all your books.  As long as you own the physical book, it should be sympatico to have the ebook version.   Then stuff most of your books in the basement in plastic bags with a dessicant pack in boxes, as these are basically just yor license to possess the ebook.

Answer (score 1):

I myself have come across this problem as I was helping a client redesign their library.  As some of the similar posters have commented you have a few different options.

My tip to you is to use as much of the vertical space you physically have.

My client didn't have 10,000 books but they did have a very healthy collection of books and we decided to use the wall to wall of built ins.  When we were researched a few different built in types we noticed that a lot of the built ins focused too much on their style that they actually sacrificed space, and when you are dealing with this many books, every inch matters.

I read a post about building a library on http://consumerhomedecor.com and the writer talked about measuring each built in precisely because although it might look bigger it might not have the same amount of carrying space that another one has.

Answer (score 0):

Had an opportunity to provide an office/library for a client (doctor-surgeon) a few years ago. He needed a work table, relaxing area, catalog research area, plus a place to keep his gazillion books.

We put the work table at one end of the room and the relaxing overstuffed chairs at the other end separated by an island for research catalogs. The island was used for laying books, research manuals, etc. on.

We raised the ceiling to 12' and extended the shelves up to maximize shelf space on TWO sides only and provided the classic rolling ladder. We also provided a narrow window, making sure the direct sunlight could not hit the books.

We proposed laying some special books on the floor in recess space and covering them with glass in two locations, but he nixed the idea...darn.

We provided a place for pictures and some special lighting to accent the two "walls of books".

I think the variety of spaces within the room helped. I'd encourage you to provide a variety of spaces, including a tv screen and computer space.

If these books are for show, I wouldn't put them in a room (library).  I'd spread them out throughout the house: entry, halls, bedrooms, etc. However, I'd keep them away from moisture like kitchen, baths, mud rooms, etc. Glass doors is a good way to protect the rare books. (There is special UV glass to protect rare books and special HVAC systems too.)